# Fatal error loading PHP via Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP file with the following code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- HEAD -->
        <?php require_once 'Language.php'; ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
             $.get('step2.php',function(data){
                 // Do something
             });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I'm trying to load some content via Ajax call. The problem is that `step2.php` contains some PHP code:

```
<div class="step-content table-bordered">
    <h3><?php echo $Lang->get('create_s2_title'); ?></h3>
</div>
```

I've already load $`Lang` object in my `Language.php` file, so what can I do to make it work? I'm getting the following error over and over again:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /home/isqawppo/public_html/web/step2.php on line 4
```

The routes are working. The problem happens when I try to use a class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`step2.php` has nothing to do with the HTML/PHP file you are making the Ajax request from.

It is a new request and runs in a completely separate, new PHP process.

You will need to include all the necessary files there, and initialize all the objects, again.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Pekka.